# How can I recognize these "default-more-or-less" type of strings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have some strings like these :

```
00. 00:00:00 - 
00. - 00:00:00 - 
00. 00:00:00 
00 - 00:00:00
00) 00:00:00
```

so, how can you see, they are similar (not equal). I need to "extrapolate" the internal block (formed by 00:00:00) and remove the rest of characters.

Every `0` in the example must be integer from `0` to `9` or the char `?`.

How can I do it on jQuery? Regex?

As starting point to check this I've made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atgC5/)

Comment: jQuery doesn't really come into this, it's just javascript's version of regex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var result = strings.match(/[\d?]{2}:[\d?]{2}:[\d?]{2}/g);
```

`result` will be an array with all the matches of `NN:NN:NN`, `??:??:??`, or any combined version of `N` and `?`.

Here is a demo for [a string with a single match](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/8xUx2/) & [a string with multiple matches](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/ayKV4/).

Comment: Yes this works. As last things (i forgot to specify in the question) I need to check also the strings that contain `?` :) Can you help me again? :)